# Why does github say it can't find my readme?

Tags: github

I have a file README.MD but I still get a message:

> We recommend adding a README to this repository. Visit github/markup
> for details on what formats we support.

Comment: Case is important. Try README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try README.md (lowercase extension)